Does firehose with MSK source and lambda transfomer support dynamic partitioning?
As per documentation I do not see mentioned anywhere that MSK does not support dynamic partitioning.
However when I am creating firehose stream from console, I do not see enable dynamic partitioning option anywhere. If I change input to other values than MSK, it appears.
If I setup s3 prefix to use partitionKeyFromLambda, it gives error that dynamic partitioning is not enabled?
Dynamic partitioning is not enabled, therefore, the prefix can't include !{partitionKeyFromQuery:keyID} or !{partitionKeyFromLambda:keyID}.
Is dynamic partitioning supported for MSK source and transformer lambda?
console error image

Confirmed with AWS support team. This is not supported yet from AWS side.
